# How to make this dynamic URL request to an API?

Tags: reactjs, api, url, axios, request

I'm trying to call an API and its URL needs to change according to what the user wants to look for.
It's SUPERHERO API, and when the user searchs for a superhero, the URL the page sends the request to needs to be modified. I'm working with Axios in React.
So, this is what I'm trying to do.

```
function App() {
const [hero, setHero] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://superheroapi.com/api/apikey/search/${hero}`)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data)
  }).catch((error)=>{
    alert("not found")
  })
}, [hero])

 return (
    <div className="App">
       <div className="input-container">
         <input id="heroName" type="text" placeholder="search hero"/>
         <button type="submit" onClick={setHero(document.getElementById("heroName").innerText)}>search</button>
       </div>
      </div>
)}

export default App;
```

the error I'm getting is TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText'). That's the part of the code I actually don't really know what I'm doing lol. My apologies, I'm a total noob.

Comment: In a React app you shouldn't be scraping the DOM for data. (It wouldn't be `innerText`, anyway--it would be `value`.) Your input's value should be in state, and you'd reference that. I don't have a more complete solution at the moment, but I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good "use" case for useRef:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

function App() => {

const textInput = useRef(null)

function handleSubmit() {
// do stuff with the input here, where the ref value is {ref}.current.value...
const hero = textInput.current.value
axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://superheroapi.com/api/apikey/search/${hero}`)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data)
  }).catch((error)=>{
    alert("not found")
  })
}

return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Type the hero name hero"
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      />
    </div>);
)}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html